# How to use sequelize to save data in node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Table Customer:

```
const Customer=sequelize.define('Customer', {
    id_customer: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
     email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
        allowNull: false
    }
// Class Method
Customer.associate = function (models) {
    Customer.belongsToMany(models.Group, {
        through :models.CustomerGroup,
        foreignKey: 'id_customer'
    });
};
```

CustomerGoup Table

```
   const CustomerGroup = sequelize.define('CustomerGroup', {
           id_customer: {
               type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
               allowNull: false,
               primaryKey: true
           },
           id_group: {
               type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
               allowNull: false,
               primaryKey: true
           }
       }
```

Group Table:

```
       module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
           const Group = sequelize.define('Group', {
                       id_group: {
                           type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
                           allowNull: false,
                           primaryKey: true,
                           autoIncrement: true
                       },
                       reduction: {
                           type: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
                           allowNull: false,
                           defaultValue: '0.00'
                       },
                       price_display_method: {
                           type: DataTypes.INTEGER(4),
                           allowNull: false,
                           defaultValue: '0'
                       },
                       show_prices: {
                           type: DataTypes.INTEGER(1).UNSIGNED,
                           allowNull: false,
                           defaultValue: '1'
                       },
                       date_add: {
                           type: DataTypes.DATE,
                           allowNull: false
                       },
                       date_upd: {
                           type: DataTypes.DATE,
                           allowNull: false
                       }
                   }


// Class Method
Group.associate = function (models) {
    Group.belongsToMany(models.Customer, {
        through :models.CustomerGroup,
        foreignKey: 'id_group'
    });
};
```

Now I am trying to save a customer to into *Customer* table. Then I need to create a record to connect customer and group. So I need to create a record in table *CustomerGroup*.
My code is as below:

```
   let newCustomer = db.Customer.build({
            email:email,

            group: [
                {id_group: 1}
            ]

        },{
            assoication: [{
                model:db.Group,
                as:'group'
            }]
        });
```

As My code, I have saved a customer information. But get error `Unhandled rejection Error: Group (group) is not associated to Customer!`

Do anybody can tell me what's problem about my code? Thanks

Comment: Customer.belongsToMany(Group)
    Group.belongsToMany(Customer)

Comment: You misspelled `assoication`, but you also need to reference it as `include`.